# need to stream to an xml directly and transport as webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, svn, jersey

We are using Java + RESTfull (jersy) webservices and return objects (xml file in svn repo) by opening a stream to an url directly.

However now I need to return a specific revision object (specific revision xml file from svn reporsitory). I am able to use svn api's and checkout that file on to the server locally. Unfortunatly I have no idea how to stream this to an url directly and transport back to client.

Could anyone guide me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

To support requesting arbitrary revisions mod_dav_svn supports a query argument.  For examples to request revision 1430000 of the CHANGES file on Subversion's trunk you'd use:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/CHANGES?p=1430000

The `p` stands for [peg revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html).  So you can even specify paths that have been deleted.  For instance this URL works:
https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/subversion/subversion-1.7.14.tar.gz.asc?p=3664

Even though trying the same URL without the peg revision argument doesn't work because the path has been deleted in the HEAD revision:
https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/subversion/subversion-1.7.14.tar.gz.asc